# Is there a service which provides audio recording within an app?

Tags: android, ios, audio-recording

I'm developing an app that would be utilizing the phone's microphone to record and store audio. However, the quality is horrible.

There are several voice recording apps that use the same mic, but their quality is exceptional.

Are there any services which would allow me to achieve this? I can recall Twilio offering something like this before, but it seems to have stopped. Basically users would be able to record audio clips and then store them for playback later. If a service can do either or both, it would be perfect.

Are you aware of any such service?

Answer (score 1):

You can start MediaRecorder in this way. Here key is `setAudioEncodingBitRate` and `setAudioSamplingRate`

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                        recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(384000);
                        recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(48000);
                        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AAC_ADTS);
                        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
                        recorder.setOutputFile(outputFile); // path of your recording in phone storage
                        try {
                            recorder.prepare();
                            recorder.start();
                            
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: " + e);
                        }
```

And you can stop Media recording in this way:

```
    private void stopRecording() {

            File file = new File(outputFile); // this is result of recording, you can play this file via MediaPlayer
 try {
            if (recorder != null) {
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.release();
                recorder = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "stopMediaRecording: ");
        }        }
```